# How can I use a link to source code in GitHub Issue?

Tags: github

I want to reference certain lines from a file in a GitHub repository in an issue. How can I do this without copying and pasting manually? Can I use a link to the source code?

To clarify, here is the file that I want to reference code from:

`mysource.py`

```
1: def func1():
2:    for i in range(10);
3:        print 'hello world'
4: 
5: def func2():
6:     for i in range(10);
7:        print 'hello world'
```

I want to quote lines 5 to 7 of the file in my issue like this:

```
5: def func2():
6:     for i in range(10);
7:        print 'hello world'
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. However, you can create line comments on the Files Changed tab of pull requests which can reference issues through the standard # referencing.

Comment: This has been possible for a few years, see @mstaessen answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27616033/6622232

Comment: This is definitely possible now. Check the steps in @Richard Dallaway's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53043820/12320578 or the full steps in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72247784/12320578

Comment: Was this answer correct at the time of posting (2014)? If it was then you shouldn't downvote it.

Answer (score 20):

You can now do this by selecting a range of lines and using the `create issue` menu option:

### Example

[image: screen shot of the menu available after selecting lines in a source file on GitHub]

...resulting in:

[image: screenshot of the resulting GitHub issue created, with a code listing inline in the issue via a link]

### Steps

1. Go to the source file
2. Select the range of lines (e.g., click the first line of interest, then <kbd>shift + click</kbd> the last line)
3. From the `...` menu on the left, select `create an issue`
4. An issue page will appear with a link to the lines, which renders as view of the source code.

Comment: I don't have the "..." options when I select the code, weird. Ideas?

Comment: Try clicking the line number in the margin in Githib: that should select the first line and give you the menu.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to open a new issue to reference the code. You could just click the "Copy permalink" button and paste the link in the text of the issue or comment.

Answer (score 11):

The key is to get a permalink to the code, that will be automatically converted to the code snippet by GitHub Markdown (GFM). After completing the steps below, the whole thing should look like this after you create an issue or comment:

[image: GitHub issue comment with the code snippet]

[Live example](https://github.com/roots/trellis-cli/issues/295#issuecomment-1126905475)

Follow these steps:

1. Go to the page with source code that needs to be referenced. For example: https://github.com/roots/trellis-cli/blob/master/cmd/venv_hook.go
2. Click on the line number next to the respective code. The selected line should now be colored with yellow, and the three dots button should appear next to the line number, like that:

   [image: Three dots button near the line number]

   **Tip:** if you want to reference multiple lines of code, click on the first line number, then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press the second line number.
3. Click on the three dots button, select "Copy permalink":

   [image: Three dots button in active state, hovered on the option "Copy permalink"]
4. Go to the issue where you want to reference the code. Paste the permalink there. The link should look like that:
   https://github.com/roots/trellis-cli/blob/a389115eb35e3c322e084183dc41497ffd67e7e0/cmd/venv_hook.go#L25-L27
   Notice that the link to the source code now has a commit SHA in the URL instead of the branch name `master`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect anymore. Did they remove this feature? Try pasting your link in any GitHub comment field, click Preview and see the result.

Comment: @silkfire Still works on my side. I've added the link to an answer where you can see a live example: https://github.com/roots/trellis-cli/issues/295#issuecomment-1126905475

Comment: @silkfire Tried adding the link on the same line as other text, it has transformed to the code snippet nonetheless, so don't think the issue is with line separators...

Comment: I figured out why it's not working. It only works within the same repository. If you link to another one it won't format it. Try e.g. https://github.com/ipjohnson/Grace.DependencyInjection.Extensions/blob/e5af2af562bd6020fd9f88204f8b866b2fad4aa4/src/Grace.DependencyInjection.Extensions/GraceRegistration.cs#L216-L234

Comment: @silkfire thanks mate, this was driving me crazy -- sometimes it seemed to work, sometimes not, never noticed this subtle difference.

Answer (score 8):

You can add the following hash-fragment.

https://github.com/username/repo/mysource.py#L5-L7

Just tried it without even knowing it was possible.